# bitcoin node running on Ubuntu is not reachable

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, bitcoin

I am running bitcoin core (v0.21.1) on my ubuntu machine (20.04.2 LTS).  I downloaded entire blockchain and configured port forwarding on my router to forward both TCP/UDP ports 8333 to the local IP address on which the node is running.  When I attempt to test inbound connection to my node using the handy tool on this website:

https://bitnodes.io/#join-the-network

I get error message in red that my node is unreachable.  What's really puzzling me is that, I followed the same set of instructions on my Windows 10 machine, and everything worked!  To make sure that it wasn't a firewall issue on my Ubuntu machine, I checked the firewall status and made sure it was inactive using this command

sudo ufw status

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this issue.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `firewalld` service was running and filtering out the communication through port 8333. This is how I fixed it:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8333/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```